# NOt able to upgrade to angular cli version 7

Tags: node.js, npm, angular-cli

we have currently running angular 6 application, we want to migrate application to angular cli version 7, but its not migrating to version 7. for migrating,  i did following steps:

```
remove node modules 
uninstall angular cli
npm install @angular/cli@latest -g
```

how to migrate to angular CLI 7?

Answer (score 0):

**Angular CLI**

The current CLI release is 6.x. which is why you aren't upgrading to 7. 7.x is currently in Release Candidate so it's not available with the normal `npm install @angular/cli` command.

**Angular**

If your current Angular project is 6 and you want to upgrade to 7, follow the guide that the Angular team built:

https://update.angular.io/

It will walk you through the steps on how to upgrade/update all your packages.

Comment: To be fair, update.angular.io, is not very useful (I'm trying to do ng version 6 to 7 migration). I just tried it, I have no idea what it wants me to do. The app complexity is confusing (how do I know which option to select. rxjs-5-to-6-migrate did nothing useful: "Cannot find any possible migrations". Removing "rxjs-compat" just broke the app. I have no idea how to get this to work.

Answer (score -1):

Just to be sure run the following steps:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache verify
```

**npm install -g @angular/cli@latest** not upgrade 6 to [CLI for Angular v7.0](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases/tag/v7.0.1)

again install previous version @angular/cli@6.2.4

***following steps***

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache verify
npm install -g @angular/cli@7.0.1
```

***step 1***

[image: steps 1]

***step 2:***  **ng -v** not available this commands

[image: steps 2]

***step 3:*** just type **ng v**

[image: steps 3]

Generate a new project and default application by running the following command:

```
ng new my-project
```

select option yes

[image]

```
cd my-project
ng serve
```

[image]

Comment: This solution doesn't answer the question. The question was how to upgrade an existing Ang6 app to version 7. This solution just shows how to upgrade the cli and create a brand new v7 app, which wasn't the question.